# Detecting orientation change on BlackBerry 9800 via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blackberry, orientation-changes, blackberry-os6, blackberry-9800

I have a bit of JavaScript (jQuery) to catch orientationchange and create a JS alert when triggered:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('body').bind('orientationchange', function(e){
        alert('orientation change triggered');
    });

});
```

link: http://jsbin.com/owebax/4

That works fine on an iPhone. It doesn't work on a BlackBerry 9800 running OS6.

In doing some googling, it appears that the issue might be that BlackBerry watches 'window' rather than 'body' for orientation change. I bound the event to `window` instead: http://jsbin.com/owebax/5

But that still doesn't work on the Blackberry (and now no longer will work on the iPhone.)

Has anyone got orientationchange JS events to fire on the BlackBerry 9800?

Comment: does this help: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Detect-screen-orientation-changes-using-JavaScript/ta-p/445755

Comment: Yes, it does! In a roundabout way it got me to play with the code some more before finally slapping my forehead in embarrassment. My answer below. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wish that in addition to 'your answer' for answering your question there was a 'embarrassing user error' flag of some sorts.

So it turns out my issue was simple syntax snafu. Instead of trying to bind to window properly as such:

```
$(window).bind...
```

I was looking for a tag called 'window'

```
$('window').bind...
```

'doh!